# C++ UDP Receving

Tags: c++, network-programming, udp

I have a problem I have been trying to iron out all day. The situation is as follows:

1. I have a server list - let's say 10 different servers.
2. I want to send a Proposal broadcast message using *sendto* command to all 10 servers.
3. I then want to listen and wait for the 10 servers to respond with an ACK + some message.
4. After some time, timeout using the data from the servers who had responded. (time will be variable based on the amount of requests)

I would like to make use of UDP so that it is connection independent, but also concerned that if I shoot out all messages at once , I might miss a message since I am not blocking on the *revfrom* line until all the messages are sent.

I could just wait after each send, but that seems inefficient from a broadcast perspective.

I could also setup a listen thread first, and then run the sendto's on a seperate thread, but then the listener (which is the whole program) is on another thread outside of main.

So my question is two fold: which of these approaches (if any) seem like the best fit given what I am trying to do? Secondly, is there any queue on the socket. Like Lets say its not 10, but 1000 servers - if a message comes in while it is not ready to receive, will this message be dropped?

I am open to suggestions on other ways to implement.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most personal computers these days are located behind firewalls that will block any incoming UDP packets --- indeed, most personal computers these days are also behind a NAT translation layer and don't even have their own Internet-routable IP address.  I'd worry about that before I'd worry about missing the occasional incoming UDP message due to timing issues.

That said, in the case where your client is running on the open Internet (or is behind a firewall that is configured to allow UDP packets in), the timing issue isn't really a problem, because the networking stack allocates an incoming-data buffer for the every socket as part of the `socket()` call.  Once you have successfully called `bind()` on the socket, any UDP packets arriving at that socket's port will be placed in to the socket's incoming-data buffer, ready to be handed over to your code the next time it calls `recvfrom()`.  Importantly, this buffering will occur whether your thread is currently inside a `recvfrom()` call, or not.

It is possible for the incoming-data-buffer to fill up (it has a finite size, usually around 64KB); at which point any additional incoming UDP packets will be dropped.  The usual way to avoid that is to make sure you call `recvfrom()` as soon as possible, or if that is not sufficient, you can use `setsockopt()` to tell the networking stack to make the socket's incoming data-buffer larger.

Meanwhile, your calls to `sendto()` will likely finish quickly, since `sendto()` returns as soon as the data in your array is copied into the socket's outgoing-data-buffer.  In particular, `sendto()` does **not** wait for the bytes to go across the network, or (usually) even for the bytes to get to your network card.  At worst, it might block until there is enough room in the outgoing-data-buffer to place the data there; and the outgoing-data-buffer is always draining at the line-speed of your network device.

Comment: This is super useful. I ran a test with a 10 sec. delay in between and saw that all messages came through. I will keep your comments about firewalls in mind. For now, this will be a local distributed cluster, so the firewall maintenance shouldn't be a huge issue, but its something to think about.  Thanks for the clarification and the detailed explanation of how this protocol works in the transport layer.